# Why the first two variables (a, b) are pre-incremented but the third one is not(c)?

Tags: c, pre-increment

I am having an issue I cannot understand. The output for a is 6, b is -6 but the c remains the same no matter what variable I initialize it with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
int a = 5, b = -7, c = 0, d;
d = ++a && ++b || ++c;
printf("\n%d%d%d%d", a, b, c, d);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Short-circuiting.

Comment: Because `A || B` evaluates to true if `A` is true or `B` is true.  If `A` is true, then you don't need to evaluate `B`, because the whole statement is true. `++a && ++b` is non-zero, hence it's evaluated as true, hence `++c` doesn't need to be evaluated and it doesn't get executed.

Comment: Not only do you not need to evaluate `B`, a compiler is *forbidden* to generate code executing side effects in `B` if `A` evaluates to true.  Related: for example `if (p == NULL || p->value == 0) ...` is safe even in case `p` can be `NULL`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is short-circuiting behavior, and a deliberate part of the C language.

When C finds an expression of the form:

```
(expression A) || (expression B)
```

And expression A is evaluated to be `TRUE`, it does not matter what expression B is!
It could be `TRUE`, or `FALSE`, but the overall expression will still be `TRUE`, because of the `||`.

As a result, the C language will not even bother to evaluate the second-half: expression B.  That part just gets skipped, and so the `++c` is skipped and never evaluated.

---

Just for kicks, if you wanted to change this program so that `++c` does happen, set `b` equal to `-1`, so that when you have `++b`, it becomes `0 (false)`.

```
int a = 5, b = -1, c = 0, d;
```

Now, the expression will evaluate this way:

```
d = (6 && 0) || [ lazy, short-circuit evaluation ];
d =    0     || [ second expression is now required! ];
d =    0     ||  1;
d = 1;
```

Output:

```
6011
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that `&&` also short-circuits if the first operand evaluates to `0` or `false`.  So for example, if `a` starts as `-1`, then `b` will not be incremented, only `a` and `c`.